# CSS3 transitions vs. jQuery animate if hardware acceleration is unavailable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, hardware-acceleration

I have an HTML5/JS app that runs in an in-dash display unit of a car.  I was using jQuery for my animations, but after finally seeing it on the hardware, I realized it was performing like crap.

I switched over to CSS3 transitions instead.  However, I just learned that CSS3 hardware acceleration is only available in SOME of the units that my app will run on.

So from what I understand, the big advantage of CSS3 transitions over jQuery .animate is hardware acceleration, right?.  But if hardware acceleration is unavailable on a particular device, am I better off using CSS3 or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can I would recommend using CSS3 as the browser can apply any necessary optimizations directly. Although I believe jQuery is moving towards leveraging CSS3 where possible for some animations.